# rails heroku deployment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

My rails application works fine in localhost, but failed to be deployed on heroku. I've searched for reasons, but apparently those methods don't work. Here is the heroku logs

```
    2012-07-25T02:17:01+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 18.111.101.88 at 2012-07-25 02:17:07 +0000
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 heroku[router]: GET thawing-scrubland-8239.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=312ms status=500 bytes=728
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 307ms
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep
2012-07-
25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)):
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 heroku[router]: GET thawing-scrubland-8239.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=31ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-07-25T02:17:07+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /favicon.ico] stale, invalid, store
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 18.111.101.88 at 2012-07-25 02:17:23 +0000
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 212ms
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)):
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-07-25T02:17:23+00:00 heroku[router]: GET thawing-scrubland-8239.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=215ms status=500 bytes=728
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 18.111.101.88 at 2012-07-25 02:17:26 +0000
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 209ms
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)):
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-07-25T02:17:26+00:00 heroku[router]: GET thawing-scrubland-8239.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=214ms status=500 bytes=728
2012-07-25T02:17:43+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 692f597 by eric61213@gmail.com
2012-07-25T02:17:43+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by eric61213@gmail.com
2012-07-25T02:17:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2012-07-25T02:17:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-07-25T02:17:46+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-07-25T02:17:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-07-25T02:17:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 13260`
2012-07-25T02:17:58+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
2012-07-25T02:17:58+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2012-07-25T02:17:58+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:13260, CTRL+C to stop
2012-07-25T02:17:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-07-25T02:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 18.111.101.88 at 2012-07-25 02:18:00 +0000
2012-07-25T02:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2012-07-25T02:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (13.8ms)
2012-07-25T02:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 375ms
2012-07-25T02:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)):
2012-07-25T02:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep
2012-07-25T02:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2012-07-25T02:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-25T02:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-07-25T02:18:01+00:00 heroku[router]: GET thawing-scrubland-8239.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=461ms status=500 bytes=728
2012-07-25T02:18:01+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /favicon.ico] miss, store
2012-07-25T02:18:01+00:00 heroku[router]: GET thawing-scrubland-8239.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=0
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved. have to set

```
config.assets.digest = true
```